# mailchimpのリストがはじかれる問題

Tags: sendmail

現在、Webサービスを運営しているのですが、サービスの機能としてメールマガジンを発行したいと考えています。
その上でメール配信用のクラウドサービスとしてMailchimpを使用したいと考えています。

それを踏まえて質問なのですが、
MailchimpでListを作成し、そこにCampaignを配信しようとしたのですが、Omnivoreに弾かれてしまい配信することができません。
下にエラーメッセージのスクリーンショットを添付しておきます。

公式リファレンスを参照しているですが、英語の能力が乏しいという理由もあり、なぜ作成したListが弾かれてしまうのか分かりません。
もし、同じような症状を解決した経験がある方や、心あたりのある方などいたら助言をいただけないでしょうか。

以下は備考です
 - Listの読み込みCSVで行っている
 - testで4つほどのメールアドレスで配信を行った場合、正常に動作した

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: かつて日に二百万通ほどメールを送信していました(SPAMじゃないですよ)。僕自身がスパマーと判定されてしまわないように[flanker](https://github.com/mailgun/flanker)であらかじめメールアドレスの有効性を確認して、配信リストの洗浄を行ってから送信していました。このライブラリはメルアドの文法のほか、DNS, MXの参照まで行って有効性を確認してくれます。ご参考まで

Answer (score 1):

リファレンスをちょっと見た感じでは、リスト内に有効でないアドレスが一定数含まれていると、はじかれる原因の一つになるようです。

有効でないアドレスというのは、タイプミスなどで元から存在しないアドレスや、古くてメールアカウントが無効になっているアドレスなど、配達できないアドレスのことです。